# How to access and use the Proximity Sensor of mobile phone through Titanium Mobile

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-android

How can I access the proximity sensor of the phone through Appcelerators Titanium Mobile API? I have been searching the web and their docs but can't seem to find anything or a concrete example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find this in the doc of Titanium.App

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-property-proximityState